# access specific data from fetched json file

Tags: jquery, json

Hi i'm new to frontend development, i have fetched json data and added it into the html as list `<li>` items but my problem is when i click on the list format json i want specific information about that that particular link i clicked to be logged into the console window.

```js
var data1={"users":[
   
  {
   "depTime":"21:30",
   "arrival":"23:30",
   "duration":"1h 45m",
   "price":"2,400",
   "planeName":"auditore",
   "stops":"non-stop",
   "image":"indiago"
  },
  {
   "depTime":"21:30",
   "arrival":"23:30",
   "duration":"1h 45m",
   "price":"2,400",
   "planeName":"auditore",
   "stops":"non-stop",
   "image":"indiago"
  }
]
         };

var output="<ul>";
    for(var i in data1.users)
    {
        output +="<li>"+
            "<a href='#'>"+"<table>"+
           "<tr>"+
               "<td>"+"<input type='radio' name='radio'>"+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+"<img src=''>"+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+data1.users[i].depTime+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+data1.users[i].arrival+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+data1.users[i].duration+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+data1.users[i].price+"</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
                 
           "<tr>"+
            "<td>"+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+data1.users[i].planeName+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+data1.users[i].stops+"</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
       "</table>"+"</a>"   +          
           "</li>";
    }
    output += "</ul>";
    
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;

    var add="<h1>";
    $("#placeholder a").click(function(){
     event.preventDefault();
     var value= //this is where i run into trouble 
                   //i want the price and depTime value of that particular <li> element which i clicked on
     console.log(value);
 });
    add+="</h1>";
document.getElementById("add").innerHTML=add;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<div id="add"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the problem actually ?

Comment: He put his actual question in a comment in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take needed value by index of `li` element:

```
$("#placeholder a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var index = $(event.currentTarget).parent().index(),
        value = data1.users[index];
    console.log(value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0f10qt27/2/

Comment: thanks for the fiddle .i was able to get exactly what i wanted just  changed the code to get only the price

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. One is to add a `data-` attribute to the `tr` tag which you can then use to get back to the data in the JSON.

Update this line to include the index:

```
 "<a href='#'>"+"<table data-index='" + i + "'>"+
```

Then in the click function

```
var index = $(this).find("table").data("index");
var valuePrice = data1.users[index].price;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `i` variable to the your li like `<li data-user-id='1'></li>`. I modified your exemple to show you how.

```js
var data1={"users":[
   
  {
   "depTime":"21:30",
   "arrival":"23:30",
   "duration":"1h 45m",
   "price":"2,400",
   "planeName":"auditore",
   "stops":"non-stop",
   "image":"indiago"
  },
  {
   "depTime":"21:30",
   "arrival":"23:30",
   "duration":"1h 45m",
   "price":"2,400",
   "planeName":"auditore",
   "stops":"non-stop",
   "image":"indiago"
  }
]
         };

var output="<ul>";
    for(var i in data1.users)
    {
        // Add i to the li as an attribute.
        output +="<li data-user-id='"+i+"'>"+
            "<a href='#'>"+"<table>"+
           "<tr>"+
               "<td>"+"<input type='radio' name='radio'>"+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+"<img src=''>"+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+data1.users[i].depTime+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+data1.users[i].arrival+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+data1.users[i].duration+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+data1.users[i].price+"</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
                 
           "<tr>"+
            "<td>"+"</td>"+
            "<td>"+data1.users[i].planeName+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+"</td>"+
               "<td>"+data1.users[i].stops+"</td>"+
           "</tr>"+
       "</table>"+"</a>"   +          
           "</li>";
    }
    output += "</ul>";
    
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;

    var add="<h1>";
    $("#placeholder a").click(function(){
     event.preventDefault();
     var value= data.user[$(this).parent('li').data('user-id')]; // get the direct parent of a which is the li that contains the data-user-id.
     console.log(value);
 });
    add+="</h1>";
document.getElementById("add").innerHTML=add;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<div id="add"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get all the child `td` elements;

```
$("#placeholder a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var tableCells = $(this).find("td");

    console.log(tableCells.get(2).innerHTML, tableCells.get(6).innerHTML);
});
```

Don't forget to pass the `event` parameter to your click handler, otherwise you should get an error on `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added couple of data attribute to the link tag which you can access it inside your click handler.

```
var value = $(this).data('deptime') + " - " + $(this).data('price');
```

If you have to access more from the object, save the index and use it to get the property inside the handler.

Check the below snippet and let me know.

```js
var data1 = {
  "users": [

    {
      "depTime": "21:30",
      "arrival": "23:30",
      "duration": "1h 45m",
      "price": "2,400",
      "planeName": "auditore",
      "stops": "non-stop",
      "image": "indiago"
    }, {
      "depTime": "21:30",
      "arrival": "23:30",
      "duration": "1h 45m",
      "price": "2,400",
      "planeName": "auditore",
      "stops": "non-stop",
      "image": "indiago"
    }
  ]
};

var output = "<ul>";
for (var i in data1.users) {
  output += "<li>" +
    "<a href='#' data-deptime='" + data1.users[i].depTime + "' data-price='" + data1.users[i].price + "' >" + "<table>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + "<input type='radio' name='radio'>" + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<img src=''>" + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + data1.users[i].depTime + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + data1.users[i].arrival + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + data1.users[i].duration + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + data1.users[i].price + "</td>" +
    "</tr>" +

    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + data1.users[i].planeName + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + data1.users[i].stops + "</td>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</table>" + "</a>" +
    "</li>";
}
output += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;

var add = "<h1>";
$("#placeholder a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).data('deptime') + " - " + $(this).data('price');
    console.log(value);
});
add += "</h1>";
document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = add;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<div id="add"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing what you wnat to acheive is to add class attribute to your td class representing what they are like `<td class="depTime">deptime_data_here</td>`.

Then in your click event, you can fetch each data you need in the dom like so :

```
 $("#placeholder a").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.find('.depTime').innerHtml();
    console.log(value);
});
```

Basically, what you need is to add information in the dom to be able to easily parse it afterwards.

You can even add an `input`in your td like `<td><input class="depTime" value="deptime_data_here"/></td>` and then use directly `val` function instead of `innerHtml` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the value as like below. Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v9c74hoz/3/)

Write new function and pass the value as what you need

```
    function selectedRow(depTime, price){
     console.log(depTime);
     console.log(price);
    }
```

And add the above function in anchor onclick

```
var output="<ul>";
    for(var i in data1.users)
    {
        output +="<li>"+
            "<a href='javascript:;' onclick='selectedRow(\""+data1.users[i].depTime+"\", \""+data1.users[i].price+"\")'>"+"<table>"+
                    "<tr>"+
                        "<td>"+"<input type='radio' name='radio'>"+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+"<img src=''>"+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+data1.users[i].depTime+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+data1.users[i].arrival+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+data1.users[i].duration+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+data1.users[i].price+"</td>"+
                    "</tr>"+

                    "<tr>"+
                        "<td>"+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+data1.users[i].planeName+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+data1.users[i].stops+"</td>"+
                    "</tr>"+
                "</table>"+"</a>"   +          
           "</li>";
    }
    output += "</ul>";

    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
```

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, you are better off using an event handler instead of an inline JS code. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html#link2